# Give an example of a module $M $ s.t. $M_m=0$ for exactly one maximal ideal, but the module is not zero

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Give an example of an $R$-module module $M$ s.t. $M_m=0$ for exactly one maximal ideal, but the module is not zero. (Here $R$ is commutative ring with unity.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a rather banal example, take $R=\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ and $M=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

The ring has only two maximal ideals, localising with $3R$ kills $M$ but with $2R$
doesn't.